# Блокировка версии браузера

Tags: html, css, webbrowser

Вообщем такая проблема не могу не где найти. Допустим как сделать что бы пользователи ie8 или других браузеров определенных версий не могли вообще зайти на мой сайт. Что бы им выводило что то типо "обновите версию браузера"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для **IE 8**  и меньше.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css">
<![endif]-->
```

И в файле `ie8-and-down.css` можете отображать то, что нужно, допустим:

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

**UPD:** Нашёл что-то [нужное.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609686/if-opera-something-different-in-css)